# Manual caret in Unity TextMesh Pro text?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to manually insert a caret/ text cursor in a 3D text TextMesh Pro text field (not a 2D input field) in Unity (C#)? I'm managing the caret position myself to indicate to the user where the typing focus is, but just need to output the `|` character into the text, without shifting successive characters.

I'm getting close by inserting `_<space=-0.525em>` into the text, but want to use the pipe character, ideally. Thanks!

Comment: How do you insert that `_<space=-0.52em>`? Can't you just insert a e.g. `|<space=-0.52em>` the same way?

Comment: Thanks, I'm manually inserting this whole substring into the main textMesh.text string, at the appropriate position. I had tried it with the | pipe as well, but it won't position appopriately (even at different space subtraction values), which might have to do with font kerning. Hmm...